# how can I comment a line with php short echo tag?

Tags: php, yii2

In my yii2 framework there are lots of line with php short echo tags `<?=`

for example:

```
<?= Html::a('Create Medicine', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'medicine_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 50]) ?>
```

I couldn't make out an easy way to comment out this lines without first changing the opening tag. is there an easy way to this?

Thanks.

Comment: No. You can't. `<?=` is pretty much identical to `<?php echo`. By commenting out the contents of the tag you're doing `<?php echo ?>`, leading to "unexpected ?>" parse errors.

Comment: Does this do the trick for you: `<?= "<!--" . ... . "-->" ?>` then it is commented in html

Comment: @rizier: bad idea, now the code is leaning out to the client. no biggie for these two, but what if there was must-never-be-seen-by-client data in there? `<?= $my_boss_is_a_total_jerkoff ?>` might not be the best thing to leak.

Comment: I think this could work for you: `<?= ""; ... ?>`, does that do the trick for you? | @MarcB You're right, but i couldn't think of something else, but i think what i know have could work

Comment: yeah, doing `<?= ""; // original stuff here` would work.

Comment: @MarcB And how wrote this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785403/how-can-i-comment-a-line-with-php-short-echo-tag/27785547#comment43980953_27785478 :D?

Comment: "you'd have to re-write all of your code". wether you go `<?=` -> `<?= ""; //` or `<?=` => `<?php // echo` doesn't matter - you're STILL rewriting all of the code.

Comment: Can you not change those 2 lines of code and instruct Yii2 not use short tags? Seems like a pain in the neck, if anything.

Comment: @MarcB `<?= ""; die(); ?>` too, wouldn't it?

Comment: @fre: probably, but since OP has multiple lines being commented out, pulling a die() in the first one is probably not what's wanted.

Comment: @MarcB Ah, you've a point there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?= ""; stuff here ?>
```

Comment: No the same result, the rest of the line is get echoed on the page.

Comment: Then your functions doesn't return stuff they print it in the function itself! So you have to rewrite your code! (You could use Notpad++ to replace stuff in the file)

Comment: But then if you have `<?php echo` then you can easily put two `//` before the echo without any problem.

Comment: @Pawan IF this works for you: `<?php //echo stuff here` and stops to be outputted, then my solution must work!

Comment: I don't know but `<?php //echo stuff` does work, but other solutions doesn't.

Comment: `<?= ""; stuff ?>` <-- stuff are your code lines like:  `Html::a('Create Medicine', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])`, so and you want to tell me that it doesn't work?

Comment: No the rest of the line get printed on the client side as code.

Comment: @Pawan How do you use my solution and what output you get? Please write it here

Comment: Thanks @Rezier123; it did work on retry. I don't know what I did wrong the first time. I am accepting ur answer as the best solution at the moment.

Comment: `<?= ""; die(); ?>` kills everything from thereon ;-) Just thinking outloud.

Answer (score 4):

I figure the easiest thing to do is replace `<?=` with `<?php //`, though it does change the opening tag...

for example

```
<?php //= Html::a('Create Medicine', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?php //= $form->field($model, 'medicine_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 50]) ?>
```

Comment: This should be the best answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<? //= Html::a('Create Medicine', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<? //= $form->field($model, 'medicine_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 50]) ?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. "Unexpected ?>" parse error. You cannot completely comment out the contents of a `<?=` block.

Comment: @MarcB - You are right. But there must be some way. isn't it?

Comment: nope. you'd have to rewrite all of the code `<?= $foo` -> `<?php // echo $foo`.

Comment: @MarcB - Ooops that's sad, Php people have not thought of it.

Comment: why should they think of it? `<?=` pretty much IMPLIES you're going to be outputting something. it'd be better to just remove the entire `<?= ... ?>` block instead.

Comment: in my example i will not completely comment out the contents of a `<?=`. There is a trick. `<? //=`. This way you will have `<? ?>` as result.

Comment: @LuisSimioni - No it prints the code in page like - `field($model, 'medicine_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => 10]) ?> ` so it doesn't work.

Comment: and if you try like this: `<? /* = $form->field($model, 'medicine_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 50]) */ ?>` ?

Comment: why don't you use start comment tag /* and end comment tag */

Comment: @unixmiah - that will outside the php tag and will have no effect, only it will be printed on the page. So far Marc B seems to right.

Comment: `<?` is considered a short open tag that is disabled by default in many configuration whereas `<?=` is enabled. If you use `<?php`, what is the advised format then you can do `<?php /* trololo */ ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= ''??Previous expression here ?>
<?= ''??Html::a('Create Medicine', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?= ''??$form->field($model, 'medicine_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 50]) ?>
```